# Post method for unchecked value in php

Tags: php, html

I am displaying list of texts with an submit button in each row called "edit".

I am using post method.

When the user want to edit more than one text they can check a checkbox and they can click on any "edit" button.And i know how handle the texts when the user checks the checkbox.

But if they want to edit only one texts then its not necessary to check checkbox.

How can i handle if the user does not check any of the check box.

For example user want to edit apartment he clicks on "edit" button which is in the same line.
How can i get the text of this in post method.
All these texts are dynamic i am getting from data base.row

```
<form method='post' action="edit.php">
<tr><td>
 <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="check_list[]">
 </td><td><input type='text' name="text[]" value="casa|house|home" /></td>
  <td><input type="submit" value="edit></td>
  </tr>
 < tr><td>
 <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="check_list[]">
 </td><td><input type='text' name="text[]" value="apartments" /></td>
  <td><input type="submit" value="edit></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the name of the Submit buttons, you'll get them in the $_POST array under that key. You can then filter the $_POST to find which button was pressed.

--- in html ---

```
<input type="submit" name="edit_1" value="edit>
```

--- in action.php ---

```
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ) {       // run over list of posted fields
  if( strpos( $key, "edit_" ) === 0 ) {     // if it starts with edit_
    $valueOfPressedButton = substr( $key, 5 ); // strip away the edit_ so that only the number of the button remains 
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that is a rather strange way to handle input and will not be straight forward in code as a result.

Comment: Can you tell me please how to handle in "edit.php" (i mean in action url page)

Comment: Recovering the key works like this. The rest you'll have to do yourself.